# Image is not showing with Positional widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, position, flutter-web

Image is not showing as I wrap the container with positioned Widget and give top any value as removed the value it is showing up. Why is that.

========================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
Here is the Code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 2,
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  Positioned(
                    top: 1,
                    child: Container(
                      // height: 30,
                      // color: Colors.red,
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 1 - 17,
                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                        image: DecorationImage(
                          image: AssetImage('home/h_intro-s1-l1.jpg'),
                          fit: BoxFit.fill,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// here you only give vertical dimensi
// but you didnt give any horizontal dimension. that caused
// the width of container will force into Positioned width, which is 0.

height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 1 - 17,
width: any value.
decoration: const BoxDecoration(
    image: DecorationImage(
        image:AssetImage('home/h_intro-s1-l1.jpg')this,
        fit: BoxFit.fill,
      )
  ),
```

[documentation Positioned:](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Positioned-class.html)
...

> Alternatively the width and height properties can be used to give the
> dimensions, with one corresponding position property

Comment: Image show up as I remove the Positioned widget  but [want to use positioned widget]. and also did that. Issue still persists.

Comment: my bad. let me try first

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `left` or `right` or `both` anchor too in order to use `Positioned` ,try this:

```
Positioned(
                    top: 1,
                    left:0,
                    right:0,
                    child: Container(
                      // height: 30,
                      // color: Colors.red,
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 1 - 17,
                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                        image: DecorationImage(
                          image: AssetImage('home/h_intro-s1-l1.jpg'),
                          fit: BoxFit.fill,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
```